# How to get an array of CNGroup from a CNContainer using CNContactStore?

Tags: swift, macos, cncontactstore

I'm looking for a way to get a list of groups ([CNGroup](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cngroup)) that relate to a contact container ([CNContainer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontainer)). When I use a [predicate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cngroup/1402794-predicateforgroupsincontainer#declarations) it fails.

The code I'm using is

```
func populateGroups(tableView:NSTableView,container:CNContainer){

    print("populateGroups.start")

    print(container.name)
    print(container.identifier)

    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

    do {
        let groupsPredicate = CNGroup.predicateForGroups(withIdentifiers: [container.identifier])
        groups = try contactStore.groups(matching: groupsPredicate)
        groupNames.removeAll();
        for group:CNGroup in groups {
            self.groupNames.append(group.name)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print( "Unexpected error fetching groups")
    }

    print("populateGroups.finish")

}
```

I'm getting an error from that doesn't make sense to me.

The line groups = try contactStore.groups(matching: groupsPredicate) causes an error.

[Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier 47008233-A663-4A52-8487-9D7505847E29, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"

Which is confusing as I'm not updating any account.

If I change that line of code to groups = try contactStore.groups(matching: nil)
I get all the groups for all the containers.

How do you create a predicate that will return all the CNGroups that belong to a CNContactContainer?

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by checking that each group from all the groups belonged to the container in question using CNContainer.predicateForContainerOfGroup

```
func populateGroups(tableView:NSTableView,container:CNContainer){

    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

    do {
        let groups:[CNGroup] = try contactStore.groups(matching: nil)
        self.groups.removeAll();
        groupNames.removeAll();
        for group:CNGroup in groups {
            let groupContainerPredicate:NSPredicate = CNContainer.predicateForContainerOfGroup(withIdentifier: group.identifier)
            let groupContainer:[CNContainer] = try contactStore.containers(matching: groupContainerPredicate)
            if( groupContainer[0].identifier == container.identifier) {
                self.groupNames.append(group.name)
                self.groups.append(group)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()

    } catch {
        print( "Unexpected error fetching groups")
    }

}
```